# What is meant by ‘threefold bliss’ in the “verses of sharing and aspiration”

Tags: terminology

What is meant by the “threefold bliss” in the verses of sharing and aspiration:

> Through the goodness that arises from my practice,
>   May my spiritual teachers and guides of great virtue,
>   My mother, my father and my relatives,
>   The Sun and the Moon,
>   and all virtuous leaders of the world –
>   May the highest gods and evil forces;
>   Celestial beings,
>   guardian spirits of the Earth and the Lord of Death;
>   May those who are friendly, indifferent or hostile;
>   May all beings receive the blessings of my life.
>   **May they soon attain the threefold bliss and realise the Deathless.**
>   Through the goodness that arises from my practice,
>   And through this act of sharing,
>   May all desires and attachments quickly cease
>   And all harmful states of mind.
>   Until I realise Nibbana,
>   In every kind of birth,
>   may I have an upright mind
>   With mindfulness and wisdom,
>   austerity and vigour.
>   May the forces of delusion not take hold nor weaken my resolve.
>   The Buddha is my excellent refuge,
>   Unsurpassed is the protection of the Dhamma,
>   The Solitary Buddha is my noble Lord,
>   The Sangha is my supreme support.
>   Through the supreme power of all these,
>   May darkness and delusion be dispelled.

via http://www.buddhamind.info/leftside/monastic/imina.htm

Answer (score 2):

[This page](https://dharmaseed.org/teacher/76/talk/2617/) ...

> 2007-11-16 **The Threefold Bliss** 55:28
>
> The talk explores worldly or human happiness, celestial or heavenly happiness and transcendent happiness or Nibbana

... says that it means:

> 1. worldly or human happiness
> 2. celestial or heavenly happiness
> 3. transcendent happiness or Nibbana

I haven't found a more canonical source for the quote i.e. I don't know where that chant comes from.

The page [Reflections on sharing blessings](http://wimutti.org/en/chants/reflections-sharing-blessings/) includes the Pali if that's helpful:

> **Puññāni pakatāni me**
>   May they soon attain
>
> **Sukhañca tividhaṃ dentu**
>   The threefold bliss
>
> **Khippaṃ pāpetha vomataṃ**
>   And realize the Deathless.

The word translated as "bliss" is *sukha*, defined [here (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sukha) and [here (PTS dictionary)](https://suttacentral.net/define/sukha).

The PTS dictionary definition includes:

> *Two* kinds, viz *kāyika* & *cetasika*; at Pts.i.188; several other pairs at AN.i.80; *three* (praise, wealth, heaven) Iti.67; another *three* (manussa˚, dibba˚, nibbāna˚) Dhp-a.iii.51; *four* (possessing, making good use of possessions, having no debts, living a blameless life) AN.ii.69

Those three ("manussa˚, dibba˚, nibbāna˚") correspond to the three identified above (i.e. "of man, of gods, and nibbana") -- though I don't understand the reference, i.e. what "Dhp-a.iii.51" means.